# How to have more than one instruction in this Chrome Extension code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'm reading Chrome Extension Docs and i'm trying to make a button changes a ID display to none.

This is what i have done so far:

```
changeColor.onclick = function(element) {
    let color = element.target.value;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
          tabs[0].id,
          {code: 'document.getElementById("topnav").style.display = "none";'});
    });
  };
```

I was trying to put a toggle, so when the button is clicked, the display comes back to block but i wanst able.

This is what i tried:

```
changeColor.onclick = function(element) {
    let color = element.target.value;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
          tabs[0].id,tabs[1].id,
          {code: 'document.getElementById("topnav").style.display = "none";'},
          {code: 'document.getElementById("topnav").style.display = "block";'});
    });
  };
```

Also tried this solution:

```
changeColor.onclick = function(element) {
    let color = element.target.value;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
              x.style.display = "block";
          } else {
              x.style.display = "none";
          }
      });
    });
  };
```

I was able to make it work outside chrome.tabs.executeScript but i need it inside, so it changes the css of the page i choose.

It probably has usesless codes for what i'm trying to do.

The reason is because i just followed https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try keeping both of your code lines inside one string. Something like : `{code: 'document.getElementById("topnav").style.display = "none"; document.getElementById("topnav").style.display = "block";'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'code' object takes in a string, simply separate them with semicolons if you have multiple instructions, for example:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { 
  code: "alert('first alert');alert('second alert')";
});
```

For the toggle effect, you could try this

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab[0].id, { 
  code: `document.getElementById('topnav').style.display = document.getElementById('topnav').style.display === 'none' 
    ? 'block' 
    : 'none'`; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your script a bit more useful by using an `if...else` statement. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

In your case I would do something like:

```
const topnav = document.getElementById("topnav");

if (topnav.style.display === 'block') {
  topnav.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  topnav.style.display = 'block';
}
```

This way, if the element is `display: block`, you set it to `display: none`, and vice-versa. Good luck!